# Switching between two Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a game that utilizes Windows Forms in C#. I want to be able to use the first form to call a second form. I have this working. Then I would like for the second form to send data back to the first form rather than creating a new instance of the first form. Can this be done? I know I need to have my properties set up so that I can set the variables from one form to the other. I am just not sure how to go about calling the first form without creating a new instance of it.
Is there a way that this can be done?
For example if I have Form A create an instance of Form B, can I have Form B do some work and send the data back to the original Form A without creating a new instance of Form A?

Comment: How about passing a reference to Form A into Form B when you construct it? Have a private field on Form B which holds a Form A reference, and go from there.

Comment: Absolutely; just save a reference to Form A in Form B. But a better way to do this is with events.

Comment: Set a variable for the data you want to send back in the second form. Then make a method that returns that variable, then call it from the first form.

Comment: @Fendorio: Wouldn't that mean Form A would have to poll Form B constantly for updates? Not sure that's ideal.

Comment: @Aaron I have a question when you send back the data to Form A do you use it right away or you use the send back data after Form B is closed?

Comment: @Baldrick Yeah you're right, I misread the question thinking he wanted to get data from the second form from the first. In that case the reference would be a good call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the Data sent back `Form A` right away then you could use the `Form_Closing` event handler `Form B` and then a public property in `Form B` also.

In your `Form A` it could look like this:

```
public partial class FormA : Form
{
    FormB frmB = new FormB(); // Instantiate FormB so that you could create an event handler in the constructor
    public FormA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Event Handler for Form Closing
        frmB.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(frmB_FormClosing);

    }

    void frmB_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        String fromFormB = frm2.FormBData; // Get Data from Form B when form is about to close
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmB.ShowDialog(); // Showing Form B
    }
 }
```

And in your `Form B` it could look like this:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       // Let just say that the data is sent back once you click a button
        FormBData = "Hello World!"; 
        Close();
   }

   public String FormBData { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I did something similar to this but with delegate. This way when form B is closed, I show the hidden form a and get some data from the second form back to the first so that it can be used in the main form. Again, thank you for your input and time answering my question.

Comment: Glad that you find a way. And thank you for accepting my answer. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing your full requirements. But generally I go like this (Somewhat psuedo code).

```
Form2 dialogForm = new Form2();
if(dialogForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
 this.PropertyOnForm1 = dialogForm.PropertyOnForm2
}
```

This ofcourse relies that your second form is a dialog. You will need to set the dialogresult buttons on Form2, and have a public property that will be accessed from Form1 once the dialog has been completed.

Let me know if this doesn't work and I'll write up a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating Form2 in `Form1`, you can create a custom event in `Form2` and subscribe to it in `Form1` at the time that you create `Form2`,  if you are returning information from `Form2` when you are closing it then Edper's or MindingData's answers will work.

Here is a quick and dirty example using [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.myCustomEvent += frm2_myCustomEvent;
        frm2.Show();

    }

    void frm2_myCustomEvent(object sender, string e)
    {
        this.Text = e;
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<string> myCustomEvent;
    int count;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count +=1;
        myCustomEvent(sender, count.ToString());
    }
}
```